# Write CSV in document with dynamic filename

Tags: external-files, strings, csv

I'm super new to Latex and I'm trying to do automatic documents that present information regarding each project. Every folder and project has a different name/code and I'd like the document to add a table from a csv file that has the same code and is present in the same folder.

The code for the csv file would be something like XX.000000000.XX.V00.csv, and I need the 0's to be different for each project (I'm trying to take them from the name of project with several concatenations).
I can't get the csv reader to use the variable as a filename. How can I solve this?
Below is my code.

```
\makeatletter
\def\csvfilename{LM.}
\g@addto@macro\csvfilename{\substring{\currfilename}{4}{12}}
\g@addto@macro\csvfilename{.PS.}
\g@addto@macro\csvfilename{\substring{\currfilename}{14}{16}}
\g@addto@macro\csvfilename{.csv}
\makeatother

\csvautotabular[separator=semicolon, respect all]{\csvfilename}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\g@addto@macro\csvfilename{\substring{\currfilename}{4}{12}}` doesn't work. Instead of adding the required substring, it literally adds the text `\substring{`followed by the original filename, followed by the literal text `{4}{12}`, etc.

The reason is that `\substring` is not expandable. Instead it writes its result in a macro `\thestring`. Therefore the solution for creating the filename is instead of all the `\g@addto@macro`s:

```
\substring{\currfilename}{4}{12}
\edef\csvfilename{LM.\thestring.PS.}
\substring{\currfilename}{14}{16}
\edef\csvfilename{\csvfilename\thestring.csv}
```

To find out what the filename has become, use

```
This is the filename: \texttt{\meaning\csvfilename}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help out. I copied your solution and inserted the filename in the \csvautotabular and got this outcome: https://linkpicture.com/q/img_1.png

Comment: That means `\csvfilename` is empty. What is your `\currfilename`? Can you post the whole LaTeX file?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I don't think \csvfilename is empty because it writes to the file. Here is the document: https://we.tl/t-gtpAXo1PSm

Comment: You shouldn't use `\csvautotabular[separator=semicolon, respect all]{\texttt{\csvfilename}}` but `\csvautotabular[separator=semicolon, respect all]{\csvfilename}. The `\texttt{}` ruins the filename given to the command.